# Why is iOS rendering a view wrong on a Plus unless I compile with the storyboard set to a Plus?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I have a storyboard with no errors or warnings, a view with subviews that centers on the main view (leading and trailing values).

With the Storyboard set to render as an 8 Plus device, it looks fine on all simulators and devices.

With the Storyboard set to render as an 8 device, it looks fine on all except Plus devices. The subviews center themselves as though the view is correctly sized and centered, while the main view itself is not wide enough. Using the view inspector, all the subviews are sizing themselves based on the correct size of the view - they're just clipped so you don't see them overlapping on the device or simulator. Notice that the clipping/too narrow view is correctly rounding the edges as well, so it's not being clipped by something else.

So far my only solution seems to be to make sure the storyboard is set to 8 Plus when compiling.

Constraints
`Leading -15 to superview`
`Trailing -15 to superview`
`Align center Y to superview`
`Height = 391`

Also tried
`Width = superview - 30`
`Align center X to superview`
`Align center Y to superview`
`Height = 391`

[image: Plus device rendering]

And here's what it looks like in the storyboard rendered on 8 Plus.

[image: Storyboard render]

Comment: That sounds like your constraints are not "relative", some values are fixed in the wrong manner or not fixed at all. Have you checked your layout constraints, are there 0 warnings?

Comment: In the question, I meant there are no errors OR warnings. All the constraints are properly relative to the parent view. Also, the view looks exactly correct in the storyboard, no matter which device I set for rendering.

Comment: Provide the details of your constraints.

Comment: Done -- added constraint details

Comment: I also tried using constraints `Equal width to superview = -30` instead of the leading/trailing, same effect.

Comment: can you remove CenterX constraint as long as there is leading and trailing

Comment: Yep, good catch ... although I'm not optimistic as it didn't work with a width constraint... nope, didn't help to remove the CenterX constraint.

Comment: What is your view hierarchy here? Is the dark-gray translucent view being added as a subview of your main view? Or is it part of a view controller that you are presenting?

Comment: The saved view that's causing the problem is at the bottom of the superview hierarchy. I added a screenshot of IB so you could see. The other views are siblings, not parents and therefore should be irrelevant.

Comment: Are you setting any conflicting constraints on a different size class?

Comment: can you try to remove leading&trailing , give it a centerX constraint and a static width say 200 and run ?

Comment: No, single constraint for Any:Any. The main question is why would it look fine on the device based on how the Storyboard is set to render? It really should NOT make any difference in how the storyboard is saved.

Comment: @Sh_Khan Hard coding a width seems to work, but doesn't help unless I change my code to add an `IBOutlet` for a width constraint and handle all devices and orientations, which would be a real pain. But maybe... just maybe... I could hard code the width constraint and then set the constant equal to the `UIScreen.main.bounds width - 30`. Let me try that .. ultimately that's just a workaround for what appears to be an Xcode bug. ... and handle a screen orientation change. Grrr...

Comment: Pffft... that didn't work either. Tried both `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`

Comment: @MattH - The white view is constrained to the translucent gray view? Are you sure the gray view is constrained properly? If you post your storyboard (as xml source on pastebin or somewhere), we could take a look...

Comment: @DonMag No, the white view is constrained to the superview. The gray view is a background that is also constrained to the superview. The gray view should have no affect on the white view - it's just behind it in the zOrder. They don't reference each other at all.

Comment: I was able to get a decent work around, NOT with the unreliable saving of the storyboard, but using a fixed width constraint for the Plus, and adjusting it for other view sizes. It seems that any calculated constraint affecting width on the Plus fails - only the absolute fixed width works, OR saving the storyboard with 8 Plus rendering.

Comment: That absolutely doesn't sound right... The white view is *not* a subview of the gray view? I suggest double-checking constraints then... In your question, you list: `Leading -15 to superview` which I assumed was a typo, as that would put it 15-pts **off** the left side of the screen.

Comment: On or off screen depends on the direction of the constraint - clearly that's not the case, and again, it doesn't answer the question of why it's fine on all devices when the storyboard is saved as 8 Plus.